# Will an unreferenced Delay task get canceled during garbage collection?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, delay, object-lifetime

Consider a  fire-and-forget delay task like this:

```cs
void Fire()
{
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1000)).ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Finally!"));
}
```

After `Fire` returns, the code no longer holds a reference to the task returned by `Delay`. So unless something is referencing the task behind the scenes, it will get garbage collected. Is that what happens? And if so, does the task get canceled?

Or is there perhaps a reference to the task in some static object in the framework that causes it to not be garbage collected, enabling it to run to completion?

Or something else? And does Microsoft document the behavior anywhere?

Comment: Nothing to worry about, the Task class does not require you to hold a reference.  It [takes care of by itself](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,24d6504222545575)

Comment: @HansPassant you should add this as an answer

Comment: I have no idea why the OP did not complete his Q+A.  Maybe it is wrong.